# Transformation Matrix of a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.
Let $A = \{ (1,2,3)^t, (1,0,4)^t,(0,0,2)^t \}$ a base of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and
$B = \{ (1,1)^t , (2,1)^t) \}$ a base of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
$$ f((x,y,z)^t) := (x,y)^t$$
I calculated the transformation matrix
$$ M_B^A(f) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  3  & -1 & 0 \\
  -1 &  1 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Should not the equation $M_B^A(f) \cdot v = f(v)$ hold true? (it does not for $v=(1,2,3)^t$) What am I understanding wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$M_B^A(f) \cdot v = f(v)$$ does not hold true.

But,

$$ M_B^A(f) \cdot [v]_{A} = [f(v)]_{B} $$

definitely does. Here $[u]_{\scr B}$ denotes the [coordinate matrix or the coordinate vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector) of $v$ with respect to the basis $\scr B$. This is the definition of the [transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix). What you say will kind of work if you use the standard bases $ \{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\} $ and $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$. But again you will not get a vector which would be a duple of the form $(x, y)$ but a matrix of the form $ \begin{pmatrix}
  x \\
  y \\  \end{pmatrix} $.